# Is it necessary to separate /home and / to different partitions?

Tags: partition, system-installation, home, root-filesystem

Is it necessary to separate /home and / to different partitions?

Here are my guesses of two benefits of separation. Suppose /home is in the partition for /.

- Is it still possible to  reinstall a Linux installation by rewriting everything except the files in /home?
- Is it still possible to share /home with  multiple Linux installations?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to separate /home and / to different partitions?

Not necessary but highly recommended.

> Is it still possible to reinstall a Linux installation by rewriting everything except the files in /home?

Yes.

> Is it still possible to share /home with multiple Linux installations?

Yes. Minor issues may occur if you co-install Ubuntu and Fedora because Fedora uses SeLinux and Ubuntu does not. `restorecon` will solve any issues regardless.

Comment: How is the first achieved? As easy as in separate partitions?

Comment: Use manual partitioning in your Linux installer. If you have a EFI computer, you must have at least `EFI system partititon` (200MB is enough), `/boot` (500MB is enough), `/` (root obviously) and `/home`. I prefer to use ext4 without LVM but you can choose anything you want. LVM/btrfs/zfs/etc. The reason I don't use them is because they make data recovery more difficult or even impossible. Backups, yes, but very few people backup daily or in real time.

Comment: You may not need /boot as partition unless using LVM. And only share /home if set as different user, otherwise similar but different versions of software may write conflicting settings. Often better then to not have separate /home, but create a large data partition and mount that in multiple installs. The /home without data is tiny.   My /home folder in / with all data in other partitions: 285.7 MiB  /home

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov What is the difference between EFI system partition and /boot? In https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-installation-partitioning, it says "NixOS by default uses the ESP (EFI system partition) as its /boot partition. It uses the initially reserved 512MiB at the start of the disk."

Comment: The EFI System partition normally contains only the boot loader(s) and it's normally quite small ~ 100MB. `/boot` traditionally existed long before GTP and it contained Linux kernels (vmlinuz) and initial ramdisks and it can go grow a lot - each kernel with its ramdisk can occupy up to 50MB. 5 installed kernel versions and it's already 250MB. You can store everything in `/boot` but lots of distros will probably won't work with this configuration. For instance Fedora needs separate /boot and EFI System partitions.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Is Linux kernel or part of it installed on /?

Comment: Yes, in addition to vmlinuz and initramfs it has files in `/lib/modules/$KERNEL_VERSION`